# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError is produced when lombok is used within a Spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok

When I am using lombok within a spring-boot application java: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError is produced. What can I do to prevent this error?

**What have I done?**

1. I've installed lombok plugin in IntelliJ and restarted it after installing plugin.
2. I've enabled Annotation Processors from both

   - File->Setting and Filer->Other Setting->Default-> setting->Build, Execution and deployment->Compiler->Annotation Processors
   - File->Setting and Filer->Setting->Build, Execution and deployment->Compiler->Annotation Processors
3. I've also tried to change the scope of dependency in the pom.xml to 'provided'
4. I tried other versions of lombok such as 1.16.21, 1.14 and ... but when I change the version other errors occur (For example when I change the version to the 1.16.16, Compiler says 'java package lombok dose not exists.')

**Errors with different versions:**
1.16.21: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

1.16.20: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

1.16.19: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

ver < 1.16.18: java: package lombok does not exist

**other info**:

JDK: 10

Spring-boot: 2.0.2.RELEASE

OS: Windows and Linux

The amount of boilerplate code (setter and getters) is really high in my code, and I really need lombok what can I do to use it?

.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem has been solved in Lombok version 1.18.0

Answer (score 4):

There is known issue with lombok and Java 10: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1572. Should be fixed with 1.16.22 version.